# How to know if observable emit was a cached BehaviourSubject value?

Tags: android, rx-java, behaviorsubject

im using a BehaviourRelay as a source observable, I like that it will emit the last cached value upon subscription, so I dont need to manually call the showPlayingState(mPlayStateManager.getCurrentState()).

However this poses a problem when I want to react with a animation in subscribe, as I dont want to run animation upon this cached emit, which gets emited when I subscribe in onCreate, UI should just jump to the state not animate to it. Animation should run only in case of a "fresh" emit

This is a fairly common use-case atleast for me, but Im having trouble figuring it out in rx

```
class Activity {

   PlayStateManager mPlayStateManager;
   Button mButton;

   void onCreate(SavedinstanceState state) {
      mPlayStateManager.playState()
        .subscribe(state -> {
           switch(state) {
            case PlayState.PLAYING:
                showPlayingState(true, ???);
                break;
            case PlayState.PAUSED:
                showPlayingState(false, ???);
                break;
           }
        }
   }

   void showPlayingState(boolean isPlay, boolean animate) {
     if(!animate) {
         mButton.setText(isPlay ? "Playing" : "Paused");
     } else {
         mButton.animate()
           .rotate(360)
           .onAnimationEnd(() -> {
              mButton.setText(isPlay ? "Playing" : "Paused");
           })
      }
   }
}


class PlayStateManager {

    BehaviourRelay<PlayState> mSubject = new BehaviourRelay();

    public void set(PlayState state) {
       mSubject.accept(state);
    }

    public Observable<PlayState> playState() {
        return mSubject.hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you don't want to perform the animation if the `playState()` is older information, but only when it switches state. In other words, on the initial call of `onCreate()`, you don't want to do the animation, but do want to do the animation if the value changes.

```
enum PlayStateExpanded {
  UNKNOWN,
  PLAYING,
  PAUSED
}

class PlayStateManager {

    BehaviourRelay<PlayStateExpanded> mSubject = 
       new BehaviourRelay(PlayStateExpanded.UNKNOWN);

    public void set(PlayState state) {
       mSubject.accept(
           state == PlayState.PLAYING ? PlayStateExpanded.PLAYING
                                      : PlayStateExpanded.PAUSED);
    }

    public Observable<PlayStateExpanded> playState() {
        return mSubject.hide();
    }
}

void onCreate(SavedinstanceState state) {
  AtomicBoolean firstTime = new AtomicBoolean(true); // note first time
  mPlayStateManager.playState()
    .subscribe(state -> {
       switch(state) {
        case PlayStateExpanded.PLAYING:
            showPlayingState(true, firstTime.get());
            break;
        case PlayStateExpanded.PAUSED:
            showPlayingState(true, firstTime.get());
            break;
       }
       firstTime.set(false); // no longer first time
    }
}
```

By redefining the play state with an `UNKNOWN` value, the start up condition is simplified. Just adding a flag for the first transition that resets after first use will accomplish your stated goal.

Comment: yes, but subject can start out empty, without the cached value

Comment: And? Your question didn't describe the behavior in such  a case. The code showed that you waited for the value to be defined.

Comment: what do you mean? behaviourrelayhas no initial default value, thereforce can be empty, thereforce will be no cached emit upon subscribe, and first "fresh" emit will be treated wrongly as such. BTW thats depending on the fact that its a behaviourrelay, which you should not know, hence the hide(), is there I way I can encode it in the data emitted maybe?

Comment: Let's back up in the design a bit. Why is the `playState()` observable undefined until it is set? It should probably always be defined, perhaps with `UNKNOWN` as its initial state.

Comment: okay, that would work. but I still dont like the fact that you have to know its behaviour

Comment: You don't have to know its behavior. You have to provide an observable that always has a state defined. There's a difference.

Comment: yes, thats good, i mean that "first emit special handling" in the subscriber, should maybe come from the stream as well, that this emit requires that kind of handling

Comment: I agree. Sometimes we don't always get the good data that we deserve and have to adjust :)

Comment: How would I do that? Subclassing BehaviorStream to emit Pair<Boolean, T> ?

Comment: Let me re-write my answer.